# android.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cygwin, android, batch-file

I have setup up the environment for cocos2d-x. I have edited the create-android-project.bat file according to my Cygwin, SDK and NDK locations. Now when I try to create a new cocos2d-x project double clicking on the create-android-project.bat file, I get errors. Please help. I am in a mess.

[image]

Comment: Did you create a Android.bat?  This seems to a problem with a script where its trying to call a file in one location when its actually in another.

Comment: Nope, it is the same android.bat that exists in \android\android-sdk.

Comment: Supply us the contents of all script files.  You have an error in one of them.

Comment: Here are the scripts : https://app.box.com/s/0kgmgksud9l374i1dyw5

Comment: Feel free to update the question's contents to include the scripts in question.

Comment: Edit your script and get rid of the extra backslash.

Comment: It's not the backslash that's causing the issue, as it should work even with the backslashes.  Dumb question, does the bat file exist in `"%_ANDROIDTOOLS%"`?  Also, looks like the script is in unix format, I don't know if that can cause an issue like this